# Is the ${u_{vs}}=0$ when $P$ is a constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, differentiation, mathematics

In Callen's book Thermodynamics and I (second edition) p.124

> To corroborate equation 4.22 show that $${\left( {\frac{{\partial P}}{{\partial s}}} \right)_T} =  - {\left( {\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial v}}} \right)_P}$$
> First consider the right-hand side, and write generally that $dT = {u_{ss}}ds + {u_{vs}}dv$
> so that $${\left( {\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial v}}} \right)_P} = {u_{ss}}{\left( {\frac{{\partial s}}{{\partial v}}} \right)_P} + {u_{vs}} =  - {u_{ss}}\frac{{{u_{vv}}}}{{{u_{sv}}}} + {u_{vs}}$$

If P is hold constant, then should  ${u_{vs}} = \frac{{\partial P}}{{\partial s}} = 0$?
Is ${u_{ss}}$ under the condition $P=constant$(i.e.Does it change in some sense compared with the situation without the condition $P=constant$ )

Comment: I see your question as perfectly within the admissible policy of this site. Actually, the exercise just triggered a conceptual question. However, you should be careful because there are people who do not read the questions carefully and follow a kind of conditioned reflexes as soon as they see the words exercise and an image from a book. :-(

Comment: I also agree that this is a priori not a homework question which should be closed (in the sense of the policy). But perhaps it could be phrased "more generally"? Why did you remove the tag, tho? @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90

Comment: @TobiasFünke Because it is a quite general conceptual question about the meaning of keeping constant a function when performing a derivative. The aspects related to homework or homework-like are irrelevant according to the original question by the OP, and I agree. It would be a mathematical question, but due to the special meaning of the quantities appearing in the present equation, it is of main interest to everybody using thermodynamics formalism, while for mathematicians it would be probably a trivial point.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thank you for saving my question!!! I will be more careful next time , Thank you!!

Comment: I see your point, but the question could've been phrased better, IMHO, make the particular question clearer. Anyway, I still think the Homework-tag applies...but okay, this is to some extend also a matter of opinion. I just want to note that just because the question is tagged as homework, this does not mean that it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, a conceptual issue should be clarified to avoid undue confusion with partial derivative manipulations, particularly those in Thermodynamics.

When we evaluate a quantity like
$$
{\left( {\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial v}}} \right)_P},\tag{1}
$$
two important things should beared in mind:

1. what $T$ is a function of (in the present case of $u$ and $v$);
2. that if the derivative is performed by keeping constant another function of the variables $T$ depends on, such a condition is valid for the limit defining the derivative in eq. $(1)$, and only there. It does not imply that we have to keep $P$ constant in every other formula.

Probably the best way of understanding why the evaluation of derivative ($1$) does not imply that $ u_{vs}= -{\left( {\frac{{\partial P}}{{\partial s}}} \right)_u} =0$ (be careful about the sign which was wrong in your question, although it is irrelevant for the whole discussion) is a simpler alternative to the long route suggested bu Callen in this exercise. The equality
$$
{\left( {\frac{{\partial P}}{{\partial s}}} \right)_T} =  - {\left( {\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial v}}} \right)_P}
$$
directly follows from [Schwartz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) on the equality of the mixed partial derivatives of a function of many variables. Indeed the required identity follows from the theorem in the case of Gibb's free energy $G(P,T)$. Each second partial derivative requires one of the two variables is kept fixed *when performing* that derivative. However, it is also clear that we are interested in the functions with their full dependence on the independent variables.